# How to run commands on user login -- that are NOT already running

Tags: ssh, command-line

I often run a series of poor-man daemons when I am sshing into my headless server.  One to [monitor the beer in my kegs](http://www.kegbot.org) and one to [monitor the server itself from a web-browser](https://github.com/Jahaja/psdash).

I do this by running both in `screen`:

```
screen -d -m psdash
screen -d -m kegbot runserver xxx.xx.x.xxx:8008
```

Both commands outside of screen tend to dominate the `stdout` in such a way it makes the rest of the `ssh` session impossible to use.  And, they also terminate with the `ssh` session, so I have found screen to be the best bet.

My question is this: is there a way in `.profile` or something else to have these commands run on login, but NOT run if they are already running?  This last bit has me out of my depth.

Comment: If in Debian: 
NAME
       start-stop-daemon - start and stop system daemon programs

SYNOPSIS
       start-stop-daemon [option...] command

DESCRIPTION
       start-stop-daemon  is  used  to control the creation and termination of
       system-level  processes.   Using   one   of   the   matching   options,
       start-stop-daemon

Comment: As a quick side note, I'd suggest using `tmux` instead of `screen`, it handles unicode much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest writing the PID (in bash that's in `$!` after starting a process) into a file, of the two processes you're starting (`psdash` and `kegbot`).

You can then use `ps --pid $(cat your.pid) |  tr -s ' ' | sed 1d | cur -d' ' -f4` to see if the process is actually running.

Just as a side note, you should always check whether the PID inside a `.pid`file is valid before acting upon it!

It might just happen that whatever mechanism you use to remove the `.pid` file when your programs stop (normally that would either be part of the program itself, or a shellscript wrapper) fails, and there's a "wrong" PID in the `.pid` file. If the `.pid` file survives a reboot, the worst-case scenario would be a PID of some other process that you'd act upon.

---

OK, here is a possible solution, using the `kegbot` as an example:

First you need a wrapper script. For simplicity's sake, let's assume everything's happening in your `$HOME`.

So, a simple wrapper (`run_kegbot.sh`) would be:

```
#!/bin/zsh
kegbot runserver xxx.xx.x.xxx:8008
echo $! > kegbot.pid
wait
rm -rf kegbot.pid
```

This is one solution, if the `kegbot` forks into the background, etc. but the PID is valid after it forks. I don't know if `kegbot` is able to handle PID files itself, which would alleviate you having to handle PID files yourself. Or, maybe you can make `kegbot` not fork into the background, and then use the shell itself (by adding a `&` to the end of line 2), to write the PID file and wait for it to finish.

Anyway, once you get the PID file malarkey done, you need something like this in your `.profile`:

```
[ -e kegbot.pid ] && {
    PID=$(cat kegbot.pid)
    COMM=$(ps -p $PID -o comm=)
    [ "x$COMM" != "xkegbot" ] && rm -f kegbot.pid 
}

[ -e kegbot.pid ] || screen -d -m ./run_kegbot.sh
```

Again, this is just *one* solution to the problem, but the general idea is to use the PID of the process to check whether it's running or not, and above is one way of doing that.

Some daemons keep their PID files in `/var/run/`, if `kegbot` and/or `psdash` do that, you obviously don't need a wrapper script, etc. since you can then use those PID files directly.

You definitely need to check, whether the PID inside a PID file is actually the process it belongs to. A rogue reboot, and/or the daemon crashing may leave a zombified PID file, etc. That's what the first test of the PID file above is for.

Comment: Would you be willing to adapt my screen commands above to illustrate this?

Comment: @chow I'll do that once I get home from work, essentially you need two wrapper scripts for the two command `psdash` and `kegbot`. Instead of the two commands directly.